# Razor web.config error - Could not load file or assembly 'Libdll.Namespace or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, servicestack

I am trying to add my custom namespace so that in .cshtml Razor files I don't need to do using every time for my Models. So I have something like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        <!-- other entries -->

        <!--works-->
        <add namespace="Libdll" />

        <!-- exception for each -->
        <add namespace="Libdll.Customnamespace1" />
        <add namespace="Libdll.Customnamespace2" />
        <add namespace="Libdll.Customnamespace2.Subnamespace" />
    </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <!-- other data -->
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Everything appears to work fine... the only problem is that during website start I get exception on this line in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new MyAppHost().Init(); // exception thrown here
}
```

The exception is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Libdll.Customnamespace1' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

True, my namespace is Libdll.Customnamespace1 in DLL named Libdll. If I just use Libdll as namespace, that will work.

So, am I missing some configuration setting in web.config? Or this is specific problem related to ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Razor config above lets you define C# namespaces included in Razor pages.

By default ServiceStack's Razor automatically references all loaded assemblies, if it can't find it, it's means it hasn't been loaded, which you should be able to do by referencing it in your Host project, e.g:

```
var loadType = typeof(Libdll.Customnamespace.CustomType);
"Assembly {0} was loaded..".Print(loadType.Assembly.FullName);
```

Comment: OK, I browsed code and see what is going on. In MarkdownFormat.cs line 98 there is foreach and Evaluator.AddAssembly. In that method there is try/catch flow control, so if I have Libdll.Customnamespace2.Subnamespace in Libdll.dll exceptions will be raised and that's why whenever I start my website I get exceptions if go Debug -> Break on all CLR exceptions. I don't see that it's possible to specify that my namespaces are in certain dll so that's not supported, right?

Comment: @kape123 It tries to be automatically inferred based on the name, so it will try to load all related assemblies from razor namespace config on its own. But I've made the [Evaluator Assembly properties public in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/63e905a5b82ca99ab57f96107d03cdc9044cf3e0), so you should be able to manually add them in the next release.

Comment: thanks for the change man. Just after viewing it I don't think it'll do it - namespaces different than assembly name will still not be loaded properly. What we need instead is to map namespaces to assemblies. I've changed that AddAssembly method to support this, please review this gist - if done that way I think it would work without errors: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9605795

Comment: @kape123 added [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/79955830086c2ffa6246d3cdf1cd19bb2d764422)